# how do i print one set of statements after my program goes through multiple if-else statements

Tags: python, if-statement

The program asks for user income for tax purposes and based on the income entered, calculates the amount of tax owed based on a series of if-else statements. The question I have is, is it possible to have just one set of  print statements at the end of the program once it is out of the if-else statements? Instead of attaching my two print statements to each if else statement?

```
taxRate = 0;
print("Please enter employee's annual taxable income ... CAD($) ")
income = eval(input())
# get the users income

# determine the amount of taxable income given three different tax rates
if income < 0:
    print("You cannot enter a negative value for the salary")

elif 0 <= income < 33389.01:
    taxrate = 0.108
    # calculate taxable income
    taxableIncome = income * taxRate
    # print tax value to two decimal places and print and tax bracket


elif 33389.01 <= income < 72164.01:
    taxrate = 0.1275
    taxableIncome = income * taxRate


else:  # income >= 72164.01
    taxrate = 0.174
    taxableIncome = income * taxRate

print("Employee's provincial tax value : CAD($) " + str(round(taxableIncome, 2)))
print("Employee's provincial tax bracket : " + str(taxRate * 100) + "% [$0 .. $33389.01)")
```

This was the code originally

```
taxRate = 0;
print("Please enter employee's annual taxable income ... CAD($) ")
income = eval(input())
# get the users income

# determine the amount of taxable income given three different tax rates
if income < 0:
    print("You cannot enter a negative value for the salary")


elif 0 <= income < 33389.01:
    taxrate = 0.108
    # calculate taxable income
    taxableIncome = income * 0.125
    # print tax value to two decimal places and print and tax bracket
    print("Employee's provincial tax value : CAD($) " + 
    str(round(taxableIncome, 2)))
    print("Employee's provincial tax bracket : " + str(.125 * 100) + "% [$0 
    .. $33389.01)")

elif 33389.01 <= income < 72164.01:
    taxrate = 0.1275
    taxableIncome = income * .1625
    print("Employee's provincial tax value : CAD($) " + 
    str(round(taxableIncome, 2)))
    print("Employee's provincial tax bracket : " + str(.1625 * 100) + "% [$0 
    .. $33389.01)")

else:  # income >= 72164.01
    taxrate = 0.174
    taxableIncome = income * .1775
    print("Employee's provincial tax value : CAD($) " + 
    str(round(taxableIncome, 2)))
    print("Employee's provincial tax bracket : " + str(.1775 * 100) + "% [$0 
    .. $33389.01)")
```

So with the one set of print statements at the end, what happens is the taxRate stays at 0 because of the assignment statement at the beginning of the program. The value stored in taxRate does change once inside the if-elif-else statements but goes back to 0 once outside of the if-elif-else statements and prints 0. I want to assign the correct taxRate for the one and only set of print statements at the end.

Comment: What's wrong with your code as written?

Comment: instructor only wants one set of print statements at the very end instead of attaching multiple copies to each if-elif-else statment

Comment: Your posted code appears to do exactly what you say you want.  Your question is therefore not at all clear.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation before we go any further.

Comment: OK, so back to the original question. Why doesn't the current code meet your requirements?

Comment: instructor says it is bad practice to have multiple if-elif-else statemets with a print statement attached to each of them instead of just ONE print statement at the very end outside of the if-elif-else statement

Comment: It's bad practice to repeat similar (or identical!) code.  Your instructor is correct.

Comment: You have typos e.g. `taxrate` vs. `taxRate`.

Answer (score 0):

here it what you are looking for

```
# get the users income
print("Please enter employee's annual taxable income ... CAD($) ")
income = eval(input())

taxRate = 0
# determine if negative income was entered
if income < 0:
    print("You cannot enter a negative value for the salary")
# determine appropriate tax rate to apply
else:
    if 0 <= income < 33389.01:
        taxRate = 0.108
        taxableIncome = income * taxRate

    elif 33389.01 <= income < 72164.01:
        taxRate = 0.1275
        taxableIncome = income * taxRate

    elif income >= 72164.01:
        taxRate = 0.174
        taxableIncome = income * taxRate
    # display tax rate and corresponding tax bracket
    print("Employee's provincial tax value : CAD($) " + str('{:.2f}'.format(taxableIncome)) + "\n" +
          "Employee's provincial tax bracket : " + str(taxRate * 100) + "% [$72164.01 .. )")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
print(
"Employee's provincial tax value : CAD($) %s \n
 Employee's provincial tax bracket : %s % [$0 .. $33389.01"  % (str(round(taxableIncome, 2)), str(taxRate * 100))
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to add a \n command at the end of the line to add a new line, possibly eliminating the need for two statements.

That would look like this:

```
    taxRate = 0;
print("Please enter employee's annual taxable income ... CAD($) ")
income = eval(input())
# get the users income

# variable declarations for tax income 3 tax rates

# determine the amount of taxable income given three different tax rates
if income < 0:
    print("You cannot enter a negative value for the salary")

elif 0 <= income < 33389.01:
    taxrate = 0.108
    # calculate taxable income
    taxableIncome = income * taxRate
    # print tax value to two decimal places and print and tax bracket


elif 33389.01 <= income < 72164.01:
    taxrate = 0.1275
    taxableIncome = income * taxRate


else:  # income >= 72164.01
    taxrate = 0.174
    taxableIncome = income * taxRate

print("Employee's provincial tax value : CAD($) " + str(round(taxableIncome, 2,"\n","Employee's provincial tax bracket : " + str(taxRate * 100) + "% [$0 .. $33389.01)")))
```